# Why is setSize not working in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to open a window with a specific `WINDOW_WIDTH` and `WINDOW_HEIGHT`.

```
/**
 * Program to calculate a tip based on a restaurant bill
 * @author Nick Gilbert
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TipCalculator extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTextField askBill;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;   // Window width
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;  // Window height

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public TipCalculator(){
        setTitle("Tip Calculator!");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel("Enter bill:");
        askBill = new JTextField(10);

        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(askBill);
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TipCalculator();
    }
}
```

Yet when I run this the width and height I specify with the `setSize` method has no effect and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `pack`

```
setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
//...
pack();
```

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29)...

> `public void pack()`
>  Causes this Window to be sized to fit the
>   preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width
>   and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of
>   dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous
>   call to the setMinimumSize method.
>  If the window and/or its
>   owner are not displayable yet, both of them are made displayable
>   before calculating the preferred size. The Window is validated after
>   its size is being calculated.

This is actually the preferred method for sizing a window as it takes into account the variations between platforms.  It also means that the window's viewable space (the area within the window's borders) matches the preferred size of it's content.

Calling `setSize` makes the widow that size, meaning that the content will be the specified size - the windows borders, which will be different for different look and feels and platforms.

Comment: @NickGilbert `pack` is actually the preferred method of calculating the size of a window

Comment: True, but you might have things that have a smaller preferred size but a much bigger possible size (scrollable things like tables/etc) that you might want your window to be bigger than the "preferred" size.

Comment: @JohnGardner The problems are, every platform renders content differently, so you go a make it look okay on your system and the next person who runs it thinks "wow, this looks a mess" :P, `setSize` it also doesn't take into account the frame border insets which effect the viewable content.  There are better solutions available the using `setSize` - I'm just saying, and yes, every situation is contextual.

Comment: `setSize` might not take that into account, but *you might have* :), or you might be using a plain JWindow with no chrome.  Sometimes `pack` is a hammer, when you need a scalpel. but yes,  sometimes `setSize` is the hammer :)